# Types with same name, same concept, but different... runtime uses?

Tags: object-oriented-design, data-types

I keep running into this problem when programming, and I wonder if someone has written about it before, or maybe developed some ideas about it.

For an example program, lets say I have a graphics program that stores, in a data file, a `Canvas`, `Layers`, and `Shapes`. Each `Canvas` has a number of `Layers`, and each `Layer` has a number of `Shapes`. The shapes are things like polygons, curves, etc. – geometric things drawn on screen. Layers represent a group of shapes that can be stacked on top of the other layers, hidden, or made transparent.

When I query the database to get a list of `Layers` in a `Canvas`, I might want to create a `Layer` type that is a pretty simple record. Something like:

```
struct Layer {
   id: UUID
   name: String
   canvasID: UUID
   zOrder: Int
   opacity: Float
}
```

Later, when the user is drawing on the screen, I might want another `Layer` class that is more complicated. It will have a list of `Shapes`. It might contain cached pointers to things like the last clicked mouse position, half-drawn shapes, data structures related to GPU rendering, etc.

I find this makes the overall design confusing, because you end up with either:

1. Multiple types named `Layer`.
2. One type named `Layer` that becomes a kind of "god class", handling too many things.

How to best deal with this problem?

Comment: It’s quite common for concepts to exist in multiple places in the code base with different levels of abstraction. Unfortunately asking for resources is off-topic. Please edit the question and focus on one single issue.

Comment: This is what namespaces are for; you could have Canvas.Layer and Screen.Layer as separate types

Comment: I'd suggest a simple system of prefixes to distinguish the same concept in related areas of the application, or different stages of processing the same data. Multiple types with the exact same name (even in different namespaces) is asking for confusion in my view, and a "god object" would be the silliest of all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a perfectly normal thing to happen. A Layer is still a layer, but for different purposes (UI or I/O) it's representation can be very different. Having a single class handle multiple representation would be at least a code smell to me, and bad practice most of the time.

So you need (at least) as many classes as you have representations of the concept. That leaves only the question of naming.

For one, I think it's fine to name both `Layer`. Ideally, only a very small portion of your codebase deals with the UI-Layer and the IO-Layer at the same time; all the rest deals only with one and it should be pretty clear which, as well.

The alternative is that you include the representation in the name (like I did in the above paragraph). This is entirely subjective and up to the team/programmers. I'd probably go with `UiLayer` and `FileLayer` (or `LayerDto`). But that's totally arbitrary.

Comment: I just realized I didn't answer the question as written... I'll suggest an edit so the Q asks for an answer rather than resources

Comment: It frustrates me that 2 of your 3 examples are in the form of *<prefix>Layer*, but your 3rd example is in the form of *Layer<Suffix>*

Comment: @PeterM what is frustrating about it? In the projects that I work in the convention would be `Layer` for the class that does the heavy lifting/app logic and `LayerDto` for the IO version. In my current project there are 5 different `Building`s... we keep them apart with various pre- and postfixes. Ugly but practical and gets the job done

Answer (score 1):

Having two classes named “layer” is asking for trouble. Less so if they are in different namespaces but it can still cause confusion.

So either make the classes identical so you only need one, or give them names that can be distinguished.